# Force include wallet optional message?

Tags: message-signing

Is there any way to force a message along with the payment using Lucid, or any other js payment? I am trying to tie an order number along with the transaction.

thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the order number as metadata.

https://lucid.spacebudz.io/docs/getting-started/make-payments/#send-ada-with-metadata